# Does "concurrency" limit of 10 guarantee 10 parallel slice runs?

Tags: azure-data-factory

In an ADF we can define concurrency limit up to maximum 10. So, assuming  we set it to 10, and slices are waiting to run (not waiting for data set dependency etc), will there always be guarantee that at any given time 10 slices will be running in parallel. I have noticed that even after setting it to 10, sometimes couple of them are in progress, or not sure if UI doesn't show properly. Is it subject to resources available? But finally it's cloud, there are infinite resources virtually. Has anyone noticed anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are 10 slices to be run in parallel and for each one of them all their dependencies have been met then 10 slices would run in parallel. Do raise an Azure support ticket if you do not see this happening and we would look into it. There may be a small delay in kicking all 10 off but 10 should run in parallel.

Thanks, Harish